# Xamarin Forms Push Notification received but not showing/appearing

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had push notifications up and working previously but now for some reason although the push notification is received, (I know it is received as it shows in Debug that a FireBaseMessage was received), it is no longer shown or a notification does not appear.

Here it can be seen that the message is received:[image]

The following is the code in my MyFireBaseMessagingService.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Util;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Firebase.Messaging;

namespace Chatfer.Droid
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
            if (message.GetNotification() != null)
            {
                //These is how most messages will be received
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
                SendNotification(message.GetNotification().Body);
            }
            else
            {
                //Only used for debugging payloads sent from the Azure portal
                SendNotification(message.Data.Values.First());

            }

        }

        void SendNotification(string messageBody)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .SetContentTitle("Chatfer Message")
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .SetContentText(messageBody)
                        .SetAutoCancel(false)
                        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);

            notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
    }
}
```

What's going on? Why did the notifications suddenly stop appearing? Any insight or suggestions would be appreciated!

**EDIT: After changing the MyFirebaseMessagingService.cs to the following, the notifications started showing again!**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Util;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Firebase.Messaging;

namespace Chatfer.Droid
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
            if (message.GetNotification() != null)
            {
                //These is how most messages will be received
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
                SendNotification(message.GetNotification().Body);
            }
            else
            {
                //Only used for debugging payloads sent from the Azure portal
                SendNotification(message.Data.Values.First());

            }

        }

        void SendNotification(string messageBody)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .SetContentTitle("Chatfer Message")
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .SetContentText(messageBody)
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .SetChannelId("YourUniqueChannelID");
            
            //var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
                // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
                // channel on older versions of Android.
                return;
            }

            var channel = new NotificationChannel("YourUniqueChannelID", "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default)
            {
                Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
            };

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);

            notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue was that I had updated my TargetAPIVersion to 26. Please refer to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/106314/android-oreo-notification-channels? for further information

Comment: Bhai, I wish I could up vote this a dozen more times. Your edit helped me fix a problem I had for days.

Comment: hahaha no problem bhai, all the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I think you don't get it is that you do not have a notification channel if you have Android V 8+ devices which I'm sure you will see to it you are registering for a notification channel in your MainActivity OnCreate method

```
void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
            // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
            // channel on older versions of Android.
            return;
        }

        var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default)
                      {
                          Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
                      };

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager) GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

Comment: You are right, I do not have this, and had recently updated the minimum API version of my app to 26. Thanks bhai

Comment: At what point, in the OnCreate, do you have to call the CreateNotificationChannel method?

Comment: @Bedir I don't think there is any such restrictions you just have to make sure you have a channel before you send a notification